# JTable fireTableStructureChanged() removes custom column renderers

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have JTable that the column name will change. After changing the column name -

```
  table.getColumnModel().getColumn(tp.ccol).setHeaderValue(newName);
  model.fireTableStructureChanged() // Does not matter if I call this or not
```

the custom render that I have set for column(0) -

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(model);
```

is completely ignored and the table is re-drawn using the default renderer for that column.

I have to reset all the Column information -

```
getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(model);
getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(40);
```

Then call

```
 model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

In order for column 0 to display properly. Is there a way around this or is this how it's suppose to work? That is a lot of hoops to go though to change the column name, and the table is re-drawn at least twice. If I use a bunch of different custom renderers this would get messy.

Thanks!

Comment: Call a repaint after setting the header value, do not call any fireXXX method on the model (not needed).

Comment: I did try that, did not work. I changed the values that represent the column names but a repaint did not actually call the function to re-get the names. Just calling the method to change the column name does the same thing, same for adding, inserting or if you change anything about the columns and want them to update.